# How to setup fitensemble for binary imbalanced datasets?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, ensemble-learning

I've been trying to test matlab's ensemble methods with randomly generated imbalance dataset and no matter what I set the prior/cost/weight parameters the method never predicts close to the label ratio.

Below is an example of the tests I did.

```
prob = 0.9; %set label ratio to 90% 1 and 10% 0
y = (rand(100,1) < prob);
X = rand(100,3); %generate random training data with three features
X_test = rand(100,3); %generate random test data 

%A few parameter sets I've tested
B = TreeBagger(100,X,y); 
B2 = TreeBagger(100,X,y,'Prior','Empirical');
B3 = TreeBagger(100,X,y,'Cost',[0,9;1,0]);
B4 = TreeBagger(100,X,y,'Cost',[0,1;9,0]);
B5 = fitensemble(X,y,'RUSBoost', 20, 'Tree', 'Prior', 'Empirical');
```

Here I tried to predict the trained classifiers on random test data. My assumption is that since the classifier is trained on random data, it should on average predict close to the dataset ratio (1/9) if it takes the prior into account. But each of the classifiers predicted 98-100% in favor of '1' instead of ~90% that I am looking for.

```
l1 = predict(B,X_test);
l2 = predict(B2,X_test);
l3 = predict(B3,X_test);
l4 = predict(B4,X_test);
l5 = predict(B5,X_test);
```

How do I get the ensemble method to take the prior into account? Or is there a fundamental misunderstanding on my part?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can work like you think.
Thats because as i understood your training and test data is random. So how should your classifier find any relation between features and your label?

lets take the accuracy as a mesurement and make an example.

class A: 900 datarows.

class B: 100 datarows.

Classify 100% as A:

> 0.9*/(0.1+0.9) = 0.9

gets you 90% Accuracy.

if your classifier does something different, means trying to classify some datarows to B he will by chance get 9 times more wrongly classified A datarows

Lets say 20 B datarows are correctly classified you will get around 180 wrong a classified A datarows

B: 20 correct, 80 incorrect

A: 720 correct, 180 wrong

> 740/(740+260) = 0.74

Accuracy goes down to 74 %. And thats not something your classifying algorithms want.

Long story short: Your classifier will allways tend to classify allmost 100% class A if you dont get any information into your Data

Comment: I don't have any label for the test data. The purpose of using the test data to see whether the predicted labels have a 90/10 distribution, which a classifier that works on imbalanced datasets should give me.

Comment: But you must have labels on your training data. Just try using some not random trainingset e.g. from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.html and imbalance it by taking away data from one class. Or do you have a reason to use random data?